# What is the relevance of the scene with Kim at the hospital?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer

In the film The Killing Of A Sacred Deer, there is a scene where Kim is on the phone with Martin. Suddenly she is able to walk and goes to the window to look for him. She can't find him. After that she loses her ability to walk again.

What is the relevance of this scene?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to this instance, both Steven and Anna don't believe Martin, and feel that the paralysis is due to a psychosomatic disorder. Anna, who views this episode firsthand, now believes in Martin being actually able to *execute* his threats (pardon the pun).

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_of_a_Sacred_Deer) will agree with me:

> Kim receives a call from Martin at the hospital. During the conversation, she regains the use of her legs, only to lose mobility again when the connection is broken. This convinces Anna that Martin has the power to follow through on his threats.